# Error 'dict' object is not callable in requesting data from tweepy API

Tags: python, json, sockets, pyspark, tweepy

I was trying to retrieve tweets via tweepy API with the following code but the json dictionary that was retrieved had an error.

The Code:

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
import socket
import json
consumer_key="****"
consumer_secret="****"
access_token="****"
access_secret="****"


class TweetListener(Stream):
    def __init__(self, *args, csocket):    
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.client_socket = csocket
 
    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            msg = json.loads(data)
            print(msg('text').encode('utf=8'))
            self.client_socket.send(msg('text').encode('utf=8'))
            return True
        except BaseException as e:
            print('Error %s'%str(e))
        return True
    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)
        return True
def send_data(c_socket):
    twtr_stream = TweetListener(
        consumer_key, consumer_secret,
        access_token, access_secret,
        csocket=c_socket
    )
    twtr_stream.filter(track=['ETH'])
s = socket.socket()
host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 5000
s.bind((host,port))
print("Active port %s"%str(port))
s.listen(5)
c, addr = s.accept()
print("request from addr "+str(addr))
send_data(c)
```

`send_data(c)` caused The Error:
`Error 'dict' object is not callable`
which kept on repeating.

I have another file that is associated with it, both these codes are required to be run simultaneously.

Code:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
sc = SparkContext(appName='StreamingTwitterAnalysis')
sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc,10)
socket_stream = ssc.socketTextStream("127.0.0.1",5000)
lines = socket_stream.window(20)
hashtags = lines.flatMap(lambda text: text.split(" ")).filter(lambda word: word.lower().startwith("#")).map(lambda word: (word.lower(),1)).reduceByKey(lambda a,b:a+b)
dstream = hashtags.transform(lambda foo: foo.sortBy(lambda x:x[0].lower()).sortBy(lambda x:x[1].ascending==False))
dstream.pprint()
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Notebook Snippet:
[image]

Comment: Can you please send the whole trace of the error?

Comment: i have added the notebook screenshot

Comment: The 1st snippet is not complete. arguments passed to *TweetListener* initializer are not defined. Please post the **complete** code or console content ([\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). Also in  *TweetListener* initializer, switch the order of *\*args* and *csocket* (`def __init__(self, csocket, *args):`).

Comment: can i share the notebooks with you?

Comment: Sure, but I don't know which would be the best way. Maybe selecting the text from the notebook and paste it to https://pastebin.com, or screen share - *TeamViewer* (or *AnyDesk*)? Also I only used notebook a few tines in the past, so I don;t have experience in that area. Does the error reproduce if you launch the script manually from console?

Comment: the error arises when i run the notebook cells

Comment: That didn't answer my question. So can you share the notebook content? Cause I got a feeling that somewhere above you have something like: `send_data = {}`.

Comment: You also pasted some keys. It's not a good idea in general to share those.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241244/discussion-between-cristifati-and-samar-pratap-singh).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In line no. 17 of the code you uploaded on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/uTuQXDBr), you load a JSON object `msg`, which is presumably a `dict`:

```py
msg = json.loads(data)
```

In line no. 18 you then call that object with a string parameter:

```py
print(msg('text').encode('utf=8'))
```

Since `dict`s are not callable, you get the mentioned error.
So I presume you wanted to access a key by that name:

```py
print(msg['text'].encode('utf=8'))
```

Comment: *OMG*, how could I have missed it? That's the  culprit!